# How to host static html page on SharePoint online

Tags: html, sharepoint, office365, onedrive, static-site

We have a simple HTML page with some embedded JS. We used to host the pages with the `.aspx` extension on the on-premises SharePoint where you can click on the file and it opens like a regular page. When doing so on an online version of SharePoint it turns out that instead of opening a page it downloads it. I tried to use SharePoint designer to point it to the page but no luck, also I tried to embed the page with the `embedded` plugin on SharePoint but it is very limited in usage (no scripts, no header with the stylesheet, etc).

So the question is how to make an online version of SharePoint to open HTML files as a regular HTML and display its content instead of downloading the pages?

Answer (score 6):

We've found the odd behavior of SharePoint in conjunction with OneDrive.
It turns out that when you upload your HTML files (with changed extension to `.aspx`) into someone's shared OneDrive or SharePoint folder directly - it will just download the pages.

But if you first upload your files into your own OneDrive and then copy/move the content to the shared folder or SharePoint's folder - it starts to open the page as it would behave in the on-premises version of SharePoint.

So the solution is to upload files **directly into your own** OneDrive and then copy/move the files to SharePoint's folder.

Comment: That actually works. Specifically, I had to do MoveTo and then choose the site. It sounds like this is a loophole they might eventually close.

Comment: It looks like this loophole has been closed. I can only move files from OneDrive to other locations that are also on OneDrive, but not to SharePoint locations.

Comment: Edit, I stand corrected, it still works. I had tried it with a folder that already was on SharePoint and was linked to OneDrive.

Comment: AND the *.aspx-files moved that way sure enough (pre)viewed perfectly in SharePoint 

Comment: It also seems to work to host the ASPX files on OneDrive, and only create a copy of the parent folder in SharePoint.

The ASPX files can then be edited on OneDrive, i.e. locally on the PC, and are synchronized with both OneDrive Online and SharePoint, keeping the ASPX files viewable on SharePoint!

Comment: Edit, I stand corrected again, the auto-sync of a folder that is on OneDrive, to SharePoint does NOT work, unfortunately.

Comment: I have now also tried using Power Automate to automatically sync the folder from OneDrive to SharePoint, but unfortunately I have not succeeded.

Comment: JFTR, this method: "if you first upload your files into your own OneDrive and then copy/move the content to the shared folder" didn't work -- at least not when using a shared folder that I had shared.

Comment: SharePoint seems to add the following things to the header of the ASPX file when it is copied from OneDrive to SharePoint:

<%@ Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" %>
<SharePoint:CTFieldRefs runat=server Prefix="o:" FieldList="FileLeafRef,Thumbnail">

Comment: Just to say thanks for this - it is missing from other posts about the subject I've seen online. Re editing: once you've uploaded this way, you CAN edit the aspx file directly and updates work. Also looks like it is only the aspx file you need to do this way, others seem fine.